# Does an orthonormal matrix preserve the $p$-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\,A\,$ be a $\,n \times k\, $ matrix, and $\,B\,$ a $\,k \times n \,$ be an orthonormal matrix.

Is it true that $\,\left\|AB\right\|_p = \left\|A\right\|_p\,$ for every $\,p\neq 2$?

Comment: I don't know this term. What is a hortonormal matrix?

Comment: There was a spelling error, a orthonormal matrix. A matrix such that $B^H B=I$.

Answer (score 2):

No, why should they be equal? It is easy to generate a counterexample. E.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0},\ B=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\ 1},\ AB=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
We have $\|AB\|_1=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\ne1=\|A\|_1$.